# How IvyDE can coexist with command-line Ant and Ivy?

Tags: java, eclipse, ivy, ivyde

I have problems running `Ivy->Resolve` from Eclipse IDE with IvyDE installed. Meanwhile, ant target

```
<target name="retrieve" unless="library.installed" description="Retrieves the libraries if needed">
    <!-- Ivy configuration - http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/ant.html -->
    <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
    <condition property="ivy.conf.name" value="java6">
        <not>
            <isset property="ivy.conf.name"/>
        </not>
    </condition>
    <echo message="Ivy conf name: ${ivy.conf.name}"/>
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml" conf="${ivy.conf.name}" checkIfChanged="false" transitive="false" />
    <ivy:retrieve conf="${ivy.conf.name}"/>
</target>
```

runs ok and without any errors. It downloads all required jar into my profile-located folder .ivy2

How to make Eclipse to use it? I see no `ivy.xml[*]` node in package explorer while `ivy.xml[*]` entry in Build Path configuration dialog exists but empty.

How to point IvyDE to jars downloaded by external Ivy?

**EDIT 1**

My problem it that IvyDE doesn't work correctly. It either hangs or cause error messages. But never works fine. What I am doing is trying to solve the problem.

So your descriptions are good, but they are for normal working Ivy.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Add the Eclipse Library

In the Libraries-Section of your projects properties click "Add Library" and choose "IvyDE Managed Dependencies"

[image]

#### 2. select the ivy.xml

Select the ivy.xml of your project and choose the appropriate configurations (**all** will do at first)

[image]

#### 3. Configure additional settings

If you have a special ivysettings.xml you can select it on the "Settings Page".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to right click on your ivy.xml and select "Add Ivy Library...".

Comment: And what then? I get Ivy configuration dialog which has no apparent place to add libraries.

Comment: Just click finish :)  It will read the ivy.xml and resolve all your dependencies.  If you have a more advanced setup, you may need to click over to the settings tab and specify your ivysettings.xml and load any properties files if your ivy.xml or ivysettings.xml is using properties from an external properties file.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't do that. I am trying it to force, but can't.

Comment: Humm.  I've seen this before.  Is there anything in [the ivy console](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/console.html).  Goto the console tab then hit the Open Console drop down and select Ivy Console.  You might see an error there.  Other than that, you might try removing any ivy.xml entries you have in your build path (Libraries tab) and try again.

Comment: And lots of times you can hit finish, but the dialog isn't dismissed, ever.  Just hit cancel.