# Install scalatest in Scala IDE for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalatest, scala-ide, sbteclipse

I have installed Eclipse Luna. Then I installed Scala IDE via `Help` -> `Install new software` and adding software site with link from [here](http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html). Then I installed sbt 0.13 and sbteclipse using [this](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/) mini-guide and created eclipse project. Then I installed (kindda) scalatest by adding it to my build.sbt. Now it looks like this:

```
val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest
  )
```

Then I created a test from [this example](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/writing_your_first_test). The file called `FirstSpec.scala` is located in `testProject/src/test/scala-2.11/testProject/`. So here is a problem: eclipse seems to not see scalaTest. The second line with `import org.scalatest._` is underlined red with error description `object scalatest is not a member of package org`. And, following [this guide](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-eclipse-plugin), I don't see the option `Run As -> ScalaTest - Suite` when choosing my test class.
At the same time everything goes good and fine when I start sbt session in my test project and type `test` command. The tests launches and passes.

So my questions are:

- why eclipse doesn't see the scalatest if I put it in `build.sbt`'s `libraryDependencies`? What's the point of libraryDependencies then?
- Why `sbt test` runs the tests without a problem? If sbt sees scalatest, why eclipse can't?

Answer (score 0):

Whew, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472840/how-to-attach-sources-to-sbt-managed-dependencies-in-scala-ide) resolved my issue. So, `build.sbt` example might go something like:

```
import com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin._

EclipseKeys.withSource := true

val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"
val jodaConvert = "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.7"
val joda = "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest
  ).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies += jodaConvert
  ).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies += joda
  )
```

Then do this:

```
rm -rf  ~/.ivy2/cache/

sbt update-classifiers

sbt eclipse
```